# Inequality with symmetric polynomials

Tags: inequalities, symmetric-functions, symmetric-polynomials, problem-solving

How to prove the inequality $a^6+b^6 \geqslant ab^5+a^5b$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: this is true iff it is true for a=1.

Comment: Even more interestingly, it is true iff it is true for a=1 and b=1.  Gerhard "Likes Better Living Through Continuity" Paseman, 2017.02.20.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a better fit for Math Stackexchange, because it's 
the kind of thing one learns from Olympiad problem books . . .
One standard approach that has not been mentioned yet:
We may assume $a,b$ are both positive (if one is zero it's easy;
if they're of opposite sign then ${\rm LHS} > 0 > {\rm RHS}$; 
and if both negative, change to $-a,-b$).  Then by the 
AM-GM inequality we have
$$
\frac56 a^6 + \frac16 b^6 \geq \bigl((a^6)^5 b^6\bigr)^{1/6} = a^5 b,
$$
and likewise $\frac16 a^6 + \frac56 b^6 \geq ab^5$, whence
the desired $a^6 + b^6 \geq a^5 b + a b^5$ follows.

Yet another possibility is to factor the difference:
$$
(a^6 + b^6) - (a^5 b + a b^5) = (a-b)^2 (a^4 + ab^3 + a^2 b^2 + ab^3 + b^4)
$$
and check that the last factor is nonnegative (e.g. it's 
$\left|(a-\rho b) \, (a-\rho^2 b)\right|^2$
where $\rho$ is a 5th root of unity).

Either way we see that equality holds **iff** $a=b$.

[*Added later*: simpler yet $-$ factor the difference as
$$
(a^6 + b^6) - (a^5 b + a b^5) = (a-b)  (a^5 - b^5),
$$
and note that $a-b$ has the same sign as $a^5-b^5$, so their product
is nonnnegative, and zero *iff* $a=b$.  Like most of the other proofs,
this generalizes to prove $a^{m+1} + b^{m+1}  \geq  a^m b + a b^m$
for all odd $m>0$, and for all real $m>0$ if $a,b \geq 0$,
with the same equality condition $a=b$ in either case.]

Answer (score 4):

Follows from Hölder's inequality (p=6, q = 6/5):

$ab^5 + ba^5 \le (a^6+b^6)^{1/6} (b^6+a^6)^{5/6}$

Answer (score 4):

This is easily proven using the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), which says that if we have two sequences of reals, and we are to pair them up in such a way as to maximize the sum of the products of the pairs, then we should pair them up according to size. From this, it immediately follows that $a^6 + b^6 \geq a^5b+ab^5$ (for consider the sequences $(a^5,b^5)$ and $(a,b)$...).

Answer (score 3):

Also follows from [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead's_inequality) since $(6,0)$ majorizes $(5,1)$.

Comment: Careful: This argument only works when $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative.

Comment: Case with $a,b$ of opposite signs is trivial, while case with $a,b$ both negative reduces to positive values by simultaneous change of signs.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very very special case of Muirhead's inequality.  It involves two multi-exponents $\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\alpha,\beta\in\bZ_{\geq 0}^n$ and the natural  action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR^n$. A permutation $\phi$ acts on the  vector $x=(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)$ by permuting the coordinates

$$\phi\cdot x=(x_{\phi(1)},\dotsc, x_{\phi(n)}). $$

(Warning: this is a right action, even though we write the $\phi$ on the left.)

We say that $\alpha \in\bZ_{\geq 0}^n$ precedes $\beta \in\bZ_{\geq 0}^n$, and we write this $\alpha\prec \beta$, if $\alpha$ lies in the convex hull of the set

$$ S_n\cdot \beta :=\big\{\; \phi\cdot\beta;\;\;\phi\in S_n\;\big\}. $$

Given $\alpha\in\bZ^n_{\geq 0}$ and $x\in\bR^n_{\geq 0}$ we define

$$ M_\alpha(x)=\sum_{\phi\in S_n} (\phi\cdot x)^\alpha= \sum_{\phi\in S_n} \prod_{k=1}^n x^{\alpha_k}_{\phi(k)}. $$

Muirhead's inequality states that

$$ \alpha\prec \beta \;\Longleftrightarrow M_\alpha(x)\leq M_\beta(x),\;\;\forall x\in\bR^n_{\geq 0}. $$

The inequality in your question corresponds to the case

$$ n=2, \;\;\alpha=(5,1)\prec \beta=(6,0),\;\; x=(a,b).$$

For more details on the rich  story behind Muirhead's inequality I refer to J. Michael Steele's   wonderful book

> *An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities. The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*, Cambridge University Press, 2004.

Comment: Careful: This argument only works when $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are correct. The general case  follows from the positive case   $$|M_{5,1}(a.b)|\leq M_{5,1}(|a|,|b|)\leq M_{6,0}(|a|.|b|)=M_{6,0}(a,b).$$